# Github Search API for pull requests: can't search for > created date (even though same code worked for searching issues)

Tags: github-api

I have some working code to search Github issues for a specific word for issues filed after a certain date. Now I wanted to modify the code so that it searched for pull requests rather than issues. So I changed the code from

```python
def search_prs(search_str, date_str, page_num):
        req = requests.get('http://api.github.com/search/issues',
                        {'q': f'{search_str}+created:>{date_str}',
                            'per_page': 100, 'page': page_num, 'sort': 'created', 'order': 'asc'},
                        headers={'Authorization': 'token ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'}, timeout=10)

    return json.loads(req.text)
```

to

```python
def search_prs(search_str, date_str, page_num):
        req = requests.get('http://api.github.com/search/issues',
                        {'q': f'{search_str}+is:pr+created:>{date_str}',
                            'per_page': 100, 'page': page_num, 'sort': 'created', 'order': 'asc'},
                        headers={'Authorization': 'token ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'}, timeout=10)

    return json.loads(req.text)
```

So, all I changed was adding "+is:pr" in the query string. However, in the latter case no results are returned, and no error is given. Is this some limitation of the Github API that ordinary users (non-enterprise) are not allowed to search by content and date range for pull requests (even though this code did work for issues)?

Comment: I've tried to find reference for this in: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search in order to help, but couldn't find anything about pr's. Anyways I'm thinking maybe try adding space/other delimiter after the 'search_str' in the modified code.